# Symfony3 - Many-to-Many bidirectional table duplication

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

here is my issue:

I've an abstract class named `UserBase` which extends all of my Users-Entity:

```
/**
* Class UserBase
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
*/
abstract class UserBase implements UserInterface, \JsonSerializable {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

....
```

In this Entity, there is a Many-To-Many bidirectional relation between a entity called `ChatConversation` :

```
 /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ChatConversation",
 *     inversedBy="users"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="chat_user_conversation",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="conversation_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $conversations;
```

`ChatConversation` class:

```
class ChatConversation {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserBase",
 *     mappedBy="conversations"
 * )
 */
private $users;
```

This code seems pretty correct for me but when I try to update the Database Schema, this leads to a error:

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gycrD.png)

I hope someone could me help to figure out what's wrong my code, thanks you !

Comment: the command scans all entities in your project in the entity directory, did you copy the file and maybe have two entities with the same table name?

Comment: @FrankB I did not copy the file and I'm sure at 100% that I do not have any other table with the specified name, I tried to change the table name with some random strings, still got the same issue.

Comment: Try the validate command "bin/console doctrine:schema:validate" to check if it gives you any errors other than that the db is not synchronized with the entities yet

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by doctrine schema update script trying to **create the "join" chat_user_conversation for each subclass** that extends UserBase.

To overcome this, you can use [Association override](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override) at the definition of your entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="conversations",
 *          joinTable=@ORM\JoinTable(
 *              name="chat_user_conversation",
 *              joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="conversation_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class Admin extends UserBase
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I solve the issue by adding a Class Table Inheritance to my main class (e.g: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). Here is what I've changed for those who have a similar problem: [Code](https://gyazo.com/733329a0413c3692fe6f52eb143312e3)